# Convert to 4-vector matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How do i convert the given complex matrix to 4 vector?

$$ S = \left(\begin{array}{c}\begin{bmatrix}-1+i & -i \\2-i & 1+3i \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}-1-7i & -9-8i \\1+10i & -6-2i \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}-11-132i & -34-31i \\7-126i & -71-5i \end{bmatrix}\end{array}\right) $$

(new in linear algebra)
I'm trying to find its span actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1} & a_{1,2}\\ a_{2,1} & a_{2,2}\end{bmatrix}$, you may choose to rewrite it as $\begin{bmatrix} a_{1,1} \\ a_{1,2} \\ a_{2,1} \\ a_{2,2}\end{bmatrix}$.

That choice is just a convenience since it is how a matrix is usually read aloud, however it is not the only choice.  What is important is however you choose to rewrite it, you keep track of *how* you rewrote it so that after you determine what the basis is you can interpret the results correctly back into the original form.

Comment: ok. thanks. i was doing it right. (but i still cannot find its span) any help? i tried row reducing it, but it gets way to complicated

Comment: It might help to consider this instead as a vector with eight entries if the arithmetic is too messy, with each entry corresponding to either the real or imaginary part of each respective entry.

Comment: @JMoravitz : Lets assume I have your 2x2 matrix. How can I now get a vector(x,y) ?

Comment: @user7185318 I do not understand your question.  A 2x2 matrix encodes four pieces of information while a vector (x, y) only encodes two pieces of information.  The question you are commenting on is quite old but was a question about finding the span of a set of matrices and how to use what they already knew about finding span of column vectors.  If you have a new unrelated question then consider opening a new question.